# Android выгрузить библиотеку

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

В `onCreate` загружаю библиотеку `System.loadLibrary("name")`.В `onDestroy` вызываю нативный метод из библиотеки который очищает все ресурсы нативные.Закрываю приложение кнопкой назад(оно остается в истории).Запускаю приложение снова, срабатывает `onCreate`.При вызове нативных методов приложение падает.Другими словами библиотека не загрузилась.Видимо она вечно висит в памяти.Да и видимо по тем же причинам не срабатывает `JNI_OnUnLoad`.Своими силами не нашел как выгрузить библиотеку, только как ее загрузить.Как выгрузить библиотеку нативную?

Comment: Вызов `onDestroy` не гарантирован, может вызываться когда угодно либо вообще никогда.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я помню библиотеку нельзя выгрузить, просто тебе нужно её грузить не в `onCreate` а в статик блоке:

```
Activity{
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("name")
   }
}
```

Comment: И как грузил.так то без разницы как грузить.как ее выгрузить вот вопрос.

Comment: Ручной выгрузки нет, а метод JNI_OnUnLoad на андроиде может и вовсе не вызываться как и onDestroy у Activity и Application. Так что не стоит рассчитывать на это.Если вам прям надо что то сделать в нативе при выгрузке приложения то делайте это в onDestroy, но как я и Евгений сказал, его вызов не гарантирован.

Comment: на некоторых устройствах действительно не срабатывает ondestroy.натив работатает с самоо начала и нужно при завершении приложения и память освободить.как быть?

Comment: Освобождайте память в onDestroy. Даже если он не вызовется то когда система прихлопнет ваш процесс она сама освободит всю занятую вами память.

Comment: бытует мнение что если на си выделить память malloc то ее нужно освободить.сама она так и не освободиться.да и регистрирую в нативе функции да бы не писать имя класса вот их тоже нужно унрегать